# How to load AWS credentials in Jenkins job DSL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, credentials, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the following DSL structure:

```
freeStyleJob {
  wrappers {
    credentialsBinding {
      [
         $class:"AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding",
         accessKeyVariable: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
         credentialsId: "your-credential-id",
         secretKeyVariable: "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
      ]
     }
   }
   steps {
      // ACCESS AWS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES HERE!
   }
}
```

However, this does not work. What is the correct syntax to do so? For Jenkins pipelines, you can do:

```
withCredentials([[
$class: "AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding",
accessKeyVariable: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
credentialsId: "your-credential-id",
secretKeyVariable: "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]]) {
  // ACCESS AWS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES HERE!
}
```

but this syntax does not work in normal DSL job groovy.

**tl;dr** how can I export AWS credentials defined by the AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding plugin into environment variables in Groovy job DSL? (NOT PIPELINE PLUGIN SYNTAX!)

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution to solve this problem:

```
wrappers {
  credentialsBinding {
    amazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding {
      accessKeyVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
      secretKeyVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
      credentialsId("your-credentials-id")
    }
  }
}
```

This will lead to the desired outcome.

Comment: Do you have the amazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding [plugin installed on your Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+AWS+Credentials+Plugin)? Also, what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to re-use Miguel's solution (even with installed aws-credentials  plugin), so here is another approach with DSL configure block

```
    configure { project ->
        def bindings = project / 'buildWrappers' / 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.SecretBuildWrapper' / 'bindings'
        bindings << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding' {
            accessKeyVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
            secretKeyVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
            credentialsId("credentials-id")
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I'm not able to re-use Miguel's solution" what is the error you are getting when using my solution?

Comment: Error is `No signature of method`. I've dig inside DSL plugin source code and found that there is no mentions of `awscredentials` at all, and package path is absolutely different for universal bindings. Definitely you have some tweaks here, any hints?

Comment: Can you give me a gist of your DSL file?

Comment: Miguel's answer is using the Automatically Generated DSL (https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Automatically-Generated-DSL). The syntax will show up in the API viewer that is embedded in Jenkins, as noted in that doc, but not in the public API viewer. One of the tradeoffs of using the auto-generated DSL vs a configure block is that it'll break the rest runner, if that's a thing you use (https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example)

Answer (score 0):

This is the full detailed answer that @bitbrain did with possible fix for issue reported by @Viacheslav

```
freeStyleJob {
    wrappers {
      credentialsBinding {
        amazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding {
          accessKeyVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
          secretKeyVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
          credentialsId("your-credentials-id")
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Ensure this is on the classpath for compilation:
`compile "org.jenkins-ci.plugins:aws-credentials:1.23"`

If you have tests running you might also need to add the plugin to the classpath:
`testPlugins "org.jenkins-ci.plugins:aws-credentials:1.23"`

I believe this is why there are reports of people needing to manually modify the XML to get this to work. Hint: if you can pass the compile stage (or compile in IDE) but not able to compile tests then this is the issue.